# mysql query with state showing "Sending data" or "Writing to net" can't be cancelled through statement.cancel() method

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connector, cancellation

I make a mysql query joining two large tables without `on` condition filter,
such as `select * from a,b`.

I hit `show processlist` command and show the sql state is being `Sending data`, then i invoke my code `statement.cancel()`.

I wonder the query has been killed ,but i'm wrong, the query is still being `Sending data` state. I notice that mysql implementation execute the following code

`if (!this.statementExecuting.get()) {
     return;
 }`

could someone have other avenue to cancel such queries ? appreciate a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried interrupting the thread that waits for the query execution to finish?

I assume you are running multiple threads as you are able to call `statement.cancel()` while the statement is being executed. So you should be able to get a reference to this thread and call `thread.interrupt()` on it.

Not sure how the JDBC driver will handle the InterruptedException - maybe you will have to take care about it in your code.

Comment: I'm sure I have invoked future.cancel(true)